# Sizes of icons for SE network sites are not equal

Tags: bug, ios-app

The sizes of one icon for a StackExchange site (English Language Learners) is bigger than another (LEGO).

Should this be the same size in the iOS app?

Comment: This is ironic, since when ELL first got its design, the icon was one of the five smallest in the network. That's been fixed, obviously. :P